# MySQL InnoDB Error

Tags: mysql, innodb, sequence, log, ibdata

I'm currently experiencing issues with my server MySQL databases as I keep receiving the following error:

```
InnoDB: The log sequence in ibdata files is higher
InnoDB: than the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles! Are database?
InnoDB: you are using the right ib_logfiles to start up the database?
InnoDB: Log sequence number in ib_logfiles in 6316712, log
InnoDB: sequence numbers stamped to ibdata file headers are between
InnoDB: 24916633497 and 24916633497
```

Hope someone can help me with this.
Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Did something happen to the ib_logfiles? Did you move/restore them?

Comment: When I first began having the issues I did not touch the files at all, but I tried restructuring the server therefore backing up, deleting then restoring the files and since then the same issue is occurring.

Comment: @Richard what mysql version are you running?

Comment: I'm running version 5.5.46

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop MySQL server;
2. Check the error log see verify if your shutdown was successful. (No errors)
3. Move your log files: mv /path/to/datadir/ib_logfile* /tmp/
4. Start MySQL server. This will create new logs;
5. When you’re absolutely sure that MySQL server has started successfully, you can remove the old log files: rm /tmp/ib_logfile*

   6. Possible roll back would be to repeat the steps again in this sequence: 1, reverse 3, 4.